# Have any GR questions been deleted since about Dec. 22?

Tags: support, questions

I'm trying to find a question involving GR that I'm positive I read on or around Dec. 22 and wanted to refer back to it but I can't find it now. It asked about an "exact" expression for either gravitational force or gravitational potential energy. It is NOT [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47783/what-is-the-exact-gravitational-force-between-two-masses-including-relativistic) because it was asked after I read the question I'm looking for and none of the answers is the answer to the question I'm looking for. So, have any GR questions been deleted recently?

Comment: I've just gotten all high and mighty and undeleted http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47379/ for the moment. I'd suggest you copy it becuase it is possible that policy will be to put it back.

Comment: Got it! THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: @dmckee just curious, was it deleted because it was a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that you are aware that you can get [a tag specific list of questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity) to sort through by clicking on the tag anywhere you find it or by specifing `[general-relativity]` in the search box?

[Combining tag search with searching for "exact"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D%20exact) might get you closer (and three undeleted and none pending ... we have such a placid site most of the time).

---

Checking [the 10k-tools page for deletions in the last 30 days](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) reveals only three such posts (questions and answers), none of which appear to involve general relativity.

Comment: Yes I've tried that extensively but with no luck. It's almost as though the question never existed.

Comment: In that case my only conclusion could be that the question did never exist, or at least that you're mistaken about some detail of this situation. I don't know of any circumstance under which a question would be deleted without showing up on that list. (It would have had to be done manually by one of the Stack Exchange developers AFAIK, and that never happens.)

Comment: I give up. I'm positive the question did exist because I went back to it several times for reference. This site gets weirder and weirder. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JoeH Manishearth reminded me on the moderation chat that deletions related to the destruction of user accounts get attributed to the Community user and do not show up on the list I used. Was the title, perhaps "What is the weight equation through general relativity?"?

Comment: YES YES THAT WAS IT!!!!!!

Comment: @dmckee Why do you want to delete that accounts, the question sounds completely valid

Comment: I think we (the moderators) are going to have to put our heads together over this. Please stand by...

Comment: LOL All I want is to print that question and its answers out. Thank goodness I now know I wasn't imagining anything.

Comment: @hwlau Long, sorry story, but it no action was taken on account of that questions, and indeed we need to find out if there is a policy on this matter and so on.

Comment: @dmckee The problem is that even the user get deleted for some reason, the question and answers should remain. Otherwise, we are lossing something valuable

Comment: @hwlau Yes, that is the issue here. Worst case any 10k user can provide the text of the question and answers, but we may want to undelete it.

Comment: @dmckee I have also rated this question, but I have to say that this behavior is really weird. I remember I see the public question counts suddenly decrease by around one hundred a week ago. It causes me think that there is a problem in my memory, but it seems it is not my problem. The feeling is weird you know.

Comment: I thought if a user account gets deleted the posts are just disassociated to not lose valuable things? 100 questions lost sounds like a very bad thing ... This must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You read the question around Dec. 22 does not mean that this question was asked on this day. If you are using the default "active" view, then it might be asked much earlier than this date. There are many people retagging questions these days, so the old questions pop up often. What you might have seen might be questions being retagged. The retagging is not very professional, so you might not see general-relativity as a tag.

If the questions your read is pretty high level, then it might probably be tagged as `[research-level]`.

Comment: It wasn't particularly high level. It was simply a derivation of a GR approximation for gravitational force (I think). I should have bookmarked it but I didn't.

Comment: @JoeH This one? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47378/mass-energy-equivalency

Comment: Sorry, no. It involved general relativity, not special relativity. It, as I recall, described a GR expression that approximates Newton's law of universal gravitation. It used the Schwarzschild metric, and I seem to recall the question being about acceleration rather than force.

Comment: @JoeH http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33950/562

Comment: Again, no. But thank you for looking. I've spent the past hour searching and it's just not here any more. I've given up. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi hwlau, this could have been an explanation. But what do you mean by "the retagging is not very professional"? It bumps the questions so Qmechanics sees them and can do final adjustments if needed, so I think it finally is quite professional. BTW I am only retagging TP questions because nobody else does, so it would be nice if you could help (and probably do much better) if you have time ;-).

Comment: @Dilaton I havent noticed Qmechanics also checking that. The first retagging seems missing some tags occasionally. The problem is that whether we should add more tags even they not very good fit, or whether we should use less tags but not so descriptive. I may join your retagging team if I have time. BTW, thanks for your hard work :)

Comment: @hwlau I usually give the tags the questions had at TP.SE, these people knew how to do it. Sometimes not all tags they had exist here, and sometimes I attach additional ones that fit in my opinion from reading the question and its answers. I think the questions should have the best tags that describe what is in them such that people interested in the topic notice the questions. Anyway, we still have Qmechanic who looks at it too as I know him :-), so all will be well.